# How to convert Rows into Columns based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have following data in a table, in table each group contain two values for ON/OFF in two rows. I want to convert rows into new columns "Col1=>Col1_Status_ON/OFF" new name based on status

here is the detail:

```
====================================================
| Group  | DateTime    | Status | Col1   |  Col2   |
====================================================
| Group1 | 01-Jan-2019 |  ON    | 101    |  102    |
| Group1 | 01-Jan-2019 |  OFF   | 201    |  202    |
| Group2 | 01-Jan-2019 |  ON    | 301    |  302    |
| Group2 | 01-Jan-2019 |  OFF   | 401    |  402    |
| Group3 | 01-Jan-2019 |  ON    | 501    |  502    |
| Group4 | 01-Jan-2019 |  OFF   | 601    |  602    |
====================================================
```

I want query that return as follows

```
    =======================================================================================
        | Group  | DateTime   |Col1_Satus_ON|Col1_Satus_OFF|Col2_Status_ON|Col2_Status_OFF|
    =======================================================================================
        | Group1 | 01-Jan-2019|   101       |   201        |    102       |   202         |
        | Group2 | 01-Jan-2019|   301       |   401        |    302       |   402         |
        | Group3 | 01-Jan-2019|   501       |   601        |    502       |   602         |        
    =======================================================================================
```

below are the SQL to generate table data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.#MyTable;
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'')[Group], GETDATE()[DateTime],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),'')[Status],(0)[Col1],(0)[Col2] 
       INTO #MyTable WHERE 1=2;

INSERT INTO #MyTable ([Group],[Datetime],[Status],[Col1],[Col2])
    SELECT 'Group1','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','ON' ,101,102 UNION
    SELECT 'Group1','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','OFF',201,202 UNION
    SELECT 'Group2','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','ON' ,301,302 UNION
    SELECT 'Group2','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','OFF',401,402 UNION
    SELECT 'Group3','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','ON' ,501,502 UNION
    SELECT 'Group3','01-Jan-2019 01:02:03','OFF',601,602;

SELECT * FROM #MyTable;
```

please suggest the query,

Comment: Hi you have to use group by and pivot

Comment: If at all possible you should consider not using reserved words as column names. It is allowed but is a real pain to work with. The reserved words typically are so vague they don't make great column names anyway.

Comment: @pascalsanchez can you write query please? –

Comment: @Haseeb see the query in answer. If you have multiple columns take look at dynamic query or at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working dynamic pivot as folks suggested

**Example**

```
Declare @UnPiv varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max)
Set @UnPiv = Stuff(( Select ','+quotename(name)
                      From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'Select top 1 * from #MyTable',null,null )  A
                      Where Name not in ('Group','DateTime','Status')
                      For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Set @SQL   = Stuff(( Select ','+quotename(name+Suffix)
                      From  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'Select top 1 * from #MyTable',null,null )  A
                      Cross Join ( values ('_Status_ON')
                                         ,('_Status_OFF')
                                 ) B(Suffix)
                       Where Name not in ('Group','DateTime','Status')
                       For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Select @SQL = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select [Group]
              ,[DateTime]
              ,Item = concat(Item,''_Status_'',Status)
              ,Value
         From  (
                 Select * From #MyTable Unpivot (Value for Item in ('+@UnPiv+')) UnPiv
               ) A
       ) src
 Pivot (max(Value) for Item in ('+@SQL+') ) pvt
'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Group], [Datetime],
    Col1_Status_ON  = MIN(IIF(Status='ON',  Col1, NULL)),
    Col1_Status_OFF = MIN(IIF(Status='OFF', Col1, NULL)),
    Col2_Status_ON  = MIN(IIF(Status='ON',  Col2, NULL)),
    Col2_Status_OFF = MIN(IIF(Status='OFF', Col2, NULL))
FROM #Mytable
GROUP BY [Group], [Datetime];
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8856b4827daff2621976fc4c6e28e51a)**

Comment: thx but above query fit for fixed columns but what about if columns are not fixed and count of col vary like col1,col2,col3 to colx.

Comment: @Haseeb  this is the query. If you have dynamic number off columns you have to combine thoses in a dynamic sql query .

Comment: @pascalsanchez ok I got it you are right!! If couldn't find best answer then I will mark your answer. :) many thanks